# Can Cypress expose function to global object?

Tags: puppeteer, cypress, end-to-end

I learned that `puppeteer` can add a function on the page's `window` object like this:

```js
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.exposeFunction('md5', text =>
    crypto.createHash('md5').update(text).digest('hex')
  );

  await page.evaluate(async () => {
    // use window.md5 to compute hashes
    const myString = 'PUPPETEER';
    const myHash = await window.md5(myString);
    console.log(`md5 of ${myString} is ${myHash}`);
  });
```

So I'm wondering is there any way that Cypress can attach functions to `window` function like puppeteer does?

Comment: The equivalent would be a [custom command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#Syntax). Cypress does it's real business in the command queue, so a function attached to window is less useful. I am wondering why puppeteer needs page.exposeFunction - I would expect `window.md5 = text => ...` to work.

Comment: @RichardMatsen Thanks, I'll check the doc about the custom command. As of `page.exposeFunction`, I think it is more powerful than just declare a function in `page.evaluate`, since we have access to Node.js native modules like `crypto` or `fs`.

Comment: Ah yes, should have noticed that. In Cypress there is a Node process running as well as the browser process. To invoke node commands such as fs you use a [task](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task.html) which is essentially an Electron IPC call. Custom commands work on the browser process, but can invoke tasks to get to the node process.

Comment: @RichardMatsen Thanks again, very informative!